# Why can't I find this drawable in the android source?

Tags: android

When I grep the android source for `divider_holo_light` I get these results:

```
~/platform_frameworks_base/core/res/res master gg divider_holo_light .
./values/arrays.xml:137:       <item>@drawable/list_section_divider_holo_light</item>
./values/arrays.xml:239:       <item>@drawable/list_divider_holo_light</item>
./values/arrays.xml:240:       <item>@drawable/list_divider_holo_light</item>
./values/styles.xml:2031:        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/list_section_divider_holo_light</item>
./values/themes.xml:1298:        <item name="listDivider">@drawable/list_divider_holo_light</item>
./values/themes.xml:1316:        <item name="listDividerAlertDialog">@android:drawable/list_divider_holo_light</item>
```

Yet when I grep the drawable directory for `divider`, this is all I see:

```
~/platform_frameworks_base/core/res/res/drawable master ls | grep divider
action_bar_divider.xml
```

Where can I find where `list_divider_holo_light` is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in `android-sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/drawable-xxx` folders.

Comment: Thanks, it's also in the android source in `~/platform_frameworks_base/core/res/res/drawable-xxx`

Comment: In which folder is your `platform_frameworks_base` located? I couldn't find that anywhere in my directories...

Comment: That's too bad. I got my sdk from Android developers website :\

Comment: I do have an sdk. That's the android source (it's different from the sdk).